# Calling from function from another asp page

Tags: asp-classic

I have two .asp pages(abc1.asp,abc2.asp). I want to call function from abc2.asp in abc1.asp pages.How to do it?

Comment: If you can't create new file and put the function there as suggested in the answer one other way is reading *abc2.asp* using FileSystemObject, extract the function as raw string and use `Execute()` method of VBScript to make it part of the context in *abc1.asp* as well. Dirty but it would work. If interested let me know and I'll come with sample code, however note it's NOT good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Create a third file, maybe called functions.asp - put your functions in that then include it in abc1.asp and abc2.asp by means of an include file statement - see below

```
<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->
```